# React: как изменить стейт переданный в функцию

Tags: reactjs, state

```
const switchInputs = (state) => {
  console.log(state.switchInput) // disabled
  this.setState(() => {
    return {
      switchInput: 'enabled'
    }
  });
}
```

Даёт ошибку:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Функция находится в другом файле, данные стейта до функции доходят

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передайте в функцию значение `this` из компонента, там у вас другая переменная `this`, отсюда и ошибка. Ведь `this` имеет разное значение при каждом вызове функции, а еще  значение `this` зависит от того, каким образом вызвана функция.

```
const switchInputs = (me, state) => {
  console.log(state.switchInput) // disabled
  me.setState(() => {
    return {
      switchInput: 'enabled'
    }
  });
}
```

Ну и вызывайте, передавая в первом параметре `this` компонента. Раньше вы вызывали функцию с одним параметром, а теперь нужно будет вызвать с двумя. Полезная ссылка для изучения: [**`this`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Вообще, так делать не рекомендуется, лучше менять стейт в самом компоненте и функции писать внутри него, дабы не породить сайд эффекты.

---

Отступая от темы передачи `this` и вызова `setState` вне компонента, хотелось бы отметить некоторые моменты.

- Это может показаться очевидным, но нужно декомпозировать и делать небольшие компоненты. То есть разделять большие компоненты на части из нескольких более мелких компонентов;
- Создавайте мелкие компоненты, старайтесь создавать их не имеющими состояния (так называемые *stateless*), это считается признаком хорошего тона;
- Также, чтобы разгрузить компоненты и переместить бизнес-логику - применяют [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started). С его помощью часть логики уходит в редьюсеры и экшны. Редьюсеры обрабатывают действия, вычисляя новое состояние. Новое состояние всего приложения отправляется в единое хранилище. Компоненты получают новое состояние через `props`;
- Совместно с Redux можно использовать [Redux-Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) - так называемые саги, и объединять бизнес-логику внутри саг, получается очень удобно, таким образом Redux становится более *легким* (сосредоточить бизнес-логику в сагах);
- Еще можно выделять функции хелперы, которые используются более чем в одном месте и не меняют состояния. Функции без изменения state можно выносить за пределы компонента и не переживать, что это может вызвать сайд эффект.

Вот так, объединяя простые и сложные подходы в разработке React приложения можно добиться чистого, понятного и не громоздкого кода. Прикрепил ссылки в описании, но всё же вынесу отдельно:

- [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)
- [Redux-Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html)

UPD: Изначально все покажется сложным, но после того, как удастся *прикрутить* Redux к своему приложения и написать несколько экшенов и редьюсеров, станет намного легче и проще. Рекомендуется начать использовать Redux на начальном этапе разработки проекта. В большой проект, не имея опыта работы с Redux, сложно будет затянуть Redux, это повлечет большие изменения и займет много времени.

Comment: У меня сейчас все функции в App, где и стейт. Но функций слишком много стало, и я хочу их вынести в отдельную папку. Как это принято делать в реакт?

Comment: @Александр добавил рекомендации в ответ. Смотрите обновленную версию.